# code to prevent skew of the view after scale in one dimension and rotation in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimage

when i am scaling the view in one direction and then rotate that time the image is stretched.
How to prevent this?
i am using the codes like the following ---

//===By Scaling Width===//

```
    float scale = [self widthResizeDistance:origin toPoint:touchLocationpoint]; // [self widthResizeDistance:origin toPoint:PrevioustouchLocationpoint];
    CGAffineTransform newTransform2 = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, scale,1.0);
    self.transform = newTransform2;
```

//===Then By Rotating===//

```
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, 1, 1);
        CGFloat previousRotation = atan2(previousDifference.y, previousDifference.x);
        CGPoint currentDifference = [self vectorFromPoint:origin toPoint:touchLocationpoint];
        CGFloat currentRotation = atan2(currentDifference.y, currentDifference.x);
        CGFloat newAngle = currentRotation- previousRotation;

        newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(newTransform, newAngle);
        self.transform = newTransform;
```